# Log of when user was logged in with MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site I am developing and it has a table that stores a log of all user activity. I am storing logins... and once a user is logged in an AJAX call (every minute) adds a new record to the log table with an updated datetime for that user. I am printing this log to the screen and want to echo when a user logs in and out without being too inefficient with the code. Not sure if this should be done in the SQL query or through PHP...

**What I want to print out:**

- User 3 logged in at [timestamp]
- User 2 logged in at [timestamp]
- User 3 logged off at [timestamp]
- User 2 logged off at [timestamp]

Log table fields would be *id, user, datetime*

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you will need php and mysql, but what's the question? what have you done so far?

Comment: Wait... did you say you were inserting a database record every minute for every user?

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to store what kind of event is being logged? Knowing something happened at 11:32am is all fine and dandy, but you'd most likely want to record that it was a login, and then a logout at 1:15pm. Or even just "nothing to report, just the by-the-minute checkin being logged".

Comment: Yes, inserting a recored for every user each minute. Cron trash collection manages how far back to maintain records. I currently loop over all records and have the log print out when the user logs in and logs out and hides all the interstitial records for each minute. I was just wondering if there was a shortcut (perhaps through the SQL query) to find JUST the login and logout times (first and last of each user session) instead of looping over all of them in php.

Comment: @Marc B - Yes, but because a user can be logged off through inactivity or closing the browser window there might not be a "logoff" event... so I am just storing the datetimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no very efficient way to do this using only PHP and MySQL. What you could do is use a query like `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE lastseen<" . $oneMinuteFromNow`.

To make this a bit more efficient you could add the result of this query in another table that makes entries for log in/out actions. That way you can filter the users given as result in the previous function.

If you want to go beyond PHP you can set a cronjob to run every minute or so, which checks who has been inactive for more than a minute, thus being offline. The code in the cronjob can then put an entry in the MySQL table to show the user logging off.